# Why do the Resources and strings.xml tabs not match?

Tags: android, xml, string

I've tried to create my own string resource 'click_me' using values > strings.xml and then using the Resources tab to add Strings. I created a few too many but I'm unable to delete the extra Strings. When I click on remove the extra Strings are not removed from the resources tab.

Yet when I switch to the strings.xml tab only the default strings remain. I would like the Resources and strings.xml tabs to sync as I'm sure they're probably meant to. What's gone wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it too and the problem is same here too. There seems to be a known issue and is posted [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57689). I suppose its only logical to edit string resource directly in xml until the issue is fixed. My Adt version and relevant information:

> Android Developer Tools
>   Build: v22.6.2-1085508
>   Blockquote